# Ruby on Rails: Iterate Through Nested Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to iterate through submitted params. Params array could be up to three level. Currently I can iterate only first level like this.

```
params[:job].each do |v, k|
    #do something with k value, only if it's string. If it's array then find its string value.
end
```

How do I iterate params when you don't know what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def nested_params(nested_hash={})  
      nested_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
        case v
          when String, Fixnum then 
            dosomething(v)
          when Hash then nested_params(v)
          else raise ArgumentError, "Unhandled type #{v.class}"
        end
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use [is_a?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F)

```
if v.is_a? Array
  # do whatever
elsif v.is_a? String
  # do whatever
else
  # something else
end
```

---

Some kind of recursive solution might be best here, such as:

```
def handle_hash hash
  hash.each do |k, v|
    if v.is_a? Hash
      handle_hash v
    elsif v.is_a? String
      # handle string
    end
  end 
end
```

And then you can just call `handle_hash params[:job]`

Comment: Since `Module.===` is a reverse of `Object.is_a?` (in that `obj.is_a? klass` is same as `klass === obj`, you can use `case` (which uses `===`) for a prettier version of your `if`: `case v; when Array then ...; when String then ...; end`